# I have an issue while opening the informatica session log

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

This is the error am getting in work flow log:

> ERROR  7/15/2020 3:00:19 PM    node01_DESKTOP-CK55616  7080    LM_36320    Session task instance [s_m_Importing_XML1]: Execution failed.

I cannot open the session log.. even session fails means also we can open the session log, but now I can't able to open the session log.

session log error:

> An internal exception occurred with [LGS_10052]

help me out!!

Comment: right click on session and click on 'get run properties' . it should show status along with error messages. Most cases this occurs when you either dint set parameters properly, dint set connections properly, session invalid or not refreshed.  you can see the picture here - https://datacadamia.com/_media/dw/etl/informatica_powercenter/powercenter_workflow_monitor_properties_statistics.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There may be few causes.

- Workflow failed to start the session at all - check workflow log.
- Session log config is invalid - review and fix
- Session log has been deleted from file system

Sharing workflow log details would shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open the session logs in case you have issue with the workflow configurations. Informatica will fail during the start of the workflow itself and there will not be any session logs, therefore it throes error when you try to open session logs. Open the workflow log, identify and fix the issue you are getting in the workflow.